# Chrome JavaScript location object

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chromium

I am trying to start 3 applications from a browser by use of custom protocol names associated with these applications. This might look familiar to other threads started on stackoverflow, I believe that they do not help in resolving this issue so please dont close this thread just yet, it needs a different approach than those suggested in other threads.

example:

```
ts3server://a.b.c?property1=value1&property2=value2
...
...
```

to start these applications I would do

```
location.href = ts3server://a.b.c?property1=value1&property2=value2
location.href = ...
location.href = ...
```

which would work in FF but not in Chrome

I figured that it might by optimizing the number of writes when there will be effectively only the last change present.

So i did this:

```
function a ()
{
  var apps = ['ts3server://...', 'anotherapp://...', '...'];

  b(apps);
}

function b (apps)
{
  if (apps.length == 0) return;

  location.href = apps[0]; alert(apps[0]);

  setTimeout(function (rest) {return function () {b(rest);};} (apps.slice(1)), 1);
}
```

But it didn't solve my problem (actually only the first `location.href` assignment is taken into account and even though the other calls happen long enough after the first one (thanks to changing the timeout delay to lets say `10000`) the applications do not get started (the alerts are displayed).

If I try accessing each of the URIs separately the apps get started (first I call `location.href = uri1` by clicking on one button, then I call `location.href = uri2` by clicking again on another button).

Replacing:

```
location.href = ...
```

with:

```
var form = document.createElement('form');
form.action = ...
document.body.appendChild(form);
form.submit();
```

does not help either, nor does:

```
var frame = document.createElement('iframe');
frame.src = ...
document.body.appendChild(frame);
```

Is it possible to do what I am trying to do? How would it be done?

EDIT:

a reworded summary

i want to start MULTIPLE applications after one click on a link or a button like element. I want to achieve that with starting applications associated to custom protocols ... i would hold a list of links (in each link there is one protocol used) and i would try to do "location.src = link" for all items of the list. Which when used with 'for' does optimize to assigning only once (the last value) so i make the function something like recursive function with delay (which eliminates the optimization and really forces 3 distinct calls of location.src = list[head] when the list gets sliced before each call so that all the links are taken into account and they are assigned to the location.src. This all works just fine in Mozilla Firefox, but in google, after the first assignment the rest of the assignments lose effect (they are probably performed but dont trigger the associated application launch))

Comment: If Aidan's answer was helpful then you should probably upvote it. If it is the best answer that you receive for this question then you can click the checkmark underneath the vote arrows to select his answer. Thank you, and welcome to SO!

Answer (score 1):

Are you having trouble looping through the elements? if so try the for..in statement [here](http://w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for_in.asp)

Or are you having trouble navigating? if so try window.location.assign(new_location);

[edit]
You can also use window.location = "...";

[edit]
Ok so I did some work, and here is what I got. in the example I open a random ace of spades link. which is a custom protocol. click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vbJxP/1/) and then click on the "click me". The comments show where the JSFiddle debugger found errors.

Comment: was this helpful? please let me know.

Comment: looping is OK (alerting the uris pops the correct alert boxes), window.location = "..." nor window.location.assign("...") helped. Thanks anyway, any other idea will be also appreciated.

Comment: I'll put your code on jsfiddle and uhh...fiddle with it. then I'll see if I can get it to work.

Comment: @JakubDaniel here is the new answer. it works just fine. I also added comments to show where the JSFiddle debugger found errors.

Comment: Well the suggested snippet of code does not iterate through the array so it cannot open all the links

Comment: @JakubDaniel hmm...could you better describe how this will work. why do you need to accomplish this?

Comment: i added a summary at the end of the question

Comment: I'm starting to think your just going to have to provide links for each application : ( I did more work but can't come up with anything

Comment: the links are useless unless you have the right associations

uac3://
ts3server://
vc1://

Comment: @Jakub what do you mean? just do <a href="myapp://theparameters"/></a>